# Android spinner items don't generate while changing localization

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to make a simple localization demo, I've got a spinner to choose language and a text view to show a string in desired language, here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
    Spinner laguageSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        laguageSpinner = laguageSpinner = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1));
        laguageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        generateLanguageItems();
    }
    public void generateLanguageItems()
    {
        laguageSpinner = laguageSpinner = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1));
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("English");
        list.add("عربي");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.el_spinner_txtview, list);
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        laguageSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int pos,
            long arg3)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos) + "",
                2000).show();
        switch(pos)
        {case 0:    changeLocale( "en" );break;
        case 1:     changeLocale( "ar" );break;}
    }

    public void changeLocale( String code )
    {
        Locale locale = new Locale(code); 
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        generateLanguageItems();
    }
}
```

the localization change code works perfectly, I've tested it by change this

```
    switch(pos)
    {case 0:    changeLocale( "en" );break;
    case 1:     changeLocale( "ar" );break;}
```

to that

```
    switch(pos)
    {case 0:    changeLocale( "ar" );break;
    case 1:     changeLocale( "en" );break;}
```

My problem here that spinner items don't generate anymore upon run I've got an empty spinner, tried to make some changes to code but with no luck, can you help me?

**---EDIT---**
As a matter of fact I tried doing this

```
public void generateLanguageItems()
{
    ....
    laguageSpinner = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1));
    laguageSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

This way spinner items do generate but `onItemSelected()` won't trigger anymore,
then I've added

```
public void generateLanguageItems()
{
            ...
    laguageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
    laguageSpinner = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1));
    laguageSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    laguageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Now it triggers recursively and i can't click on spinner and inflate its items!

Comment: I've added a condition to stop recursion, I'll post my code in case of anybody got that porblem too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a condition to break recursion, here is the working code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
    Spinner laguageSpinner;
    int currentLocale=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        laguageSpinner = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1));
        laguageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        generateLanguageItems(0);
    }
    public void generateLanguageItems(int pos)
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("English");
        list.add("عربي");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.el_spinner_txtview, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        laguageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
        laguageSpinner = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1));
        laguageSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        laguageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        laguageSpinner.setSelection(pos);
        currentLocale = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int pos, long arg3)
    {   changeLocale(  pos );   }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
    {   }

    public void changeLocale( int pos )
    {
        if ( currentLocale == pos)
            return;
        Locale locale;
        if (pos == 0)
            locale = new Locale("en");
        else
            locale = new Locale("ar");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        generateLanguageItems(pos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this double assignment:

```
laguageSpinner = laguageSpinner = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1));
```

Change that to

```
laguageSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

and try again.

Comment: You have it in 2 spots. Did you change it in both?